# Assign null to integer in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a winforms application and i am trying to pass 5 parameters inside the tableadapter in order to execute a query but i get the error "Cannot convert from 'int?' to 'int'. All of them can be nulls.

```cs
private int? c_id ;
private string c_cn;
private int? c_afm;
private string c_job;
private string c_city;

private void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
c_id = (txtBox_id.Text != string.Empty) ? c_id = Convert.ToInt32(txtBox_id.Text) : c_id = null;
c_afm = (txtBox_afm.Text != string.Empty) ? c_afm = Convert.ToInt32(txtBox_afm.Text) : c_afm = null;
c_cn = (txtBox_cn.Text != string.Empty) ? c_cn = txtBox_cn.Text : c_cn = null;
c_job = (txtBox_job.Text != string.Empty) ? c_job = txtBox_job.Text : c_job = null;
c_city = (txtBox_job.Text != string.Empty) ? c_city = txtBox_city.Text : c_city = null;

this.clientBrowserTableAdapter.Fill(erpDataSet.PelatesBrowser,c_id,c_cn,c_afm, c_job,c_city);
}
```

The problem is at c_id and c_afm parameters. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you have a bug in the assignment to `c_city`, the ternary operator checks if `txtBox_job.Text` is not empty, instead of `txtBox_city.Text`.

Comment: You don't need to assign inside the ternary operator, just assign the returned value .

`c_id = (txtBox_id.Text != string.Empty) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtBox_id.Text) : null;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dedicated method for converting string to `int?`

```
private int? ConvertToDbInt(string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        return null;
    }

    return int.Parse(text);
}
```

Then reuse it for different variables

```
c_id = ConvertToDbInt(txtBox_id.Text);
c_afm = ConvertToDbInt(txtBox_afm.Text);
```

Your actual problem is because conditional operator `?:` expects that both positive and negative expressions produce value of same type, where in your case it is `int` - for positive and `int?` for negative.

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression **must be the
>   same**, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

If you big fan of conditional operator `?:` then just make sure that both expression returns same type, `int?` in your case.

```
c_id = (txtBox_id.Text != string.Empty) ? (int?)Convert.ToInt32(txtBox_id.Text) : null;
```

When exception thrown on line `this.clientBrowserTableAdapter.Fill(...`, that mean that `Fill` method expects parameter of type `int`, you can easily convert nullable int to int by calling `.GetValueOrDefault()`

```
this.clientBrowserTableAdapter.Fill(
    erpDataSet.PelatesBrowser,
    c_id.GetValueOrDefault(),
    c_cn,
    c_afm.GetValueOrDefault(), 
    c_job,
    c_city);
```

Comment: on tableadapter.fill method, c_id parameter

Comment: @NikosL24, that mean, that `.Fill` method expects parameter of type `int`, check updated answer how you can convert `int?` to `int`

Comment: Ok it stopped throwing the error. Now i need to find why i dont get any data back from the table adapter lol

Answer (score 1):

`clientBrowserTableAdapter.Fill` is expecting an `int`. You are passing a `Nullable<int>`, they are not the same and there is no implicit conversion happening. You either need to cast it to `int` i.e `(int)c_id` or use `.Value` property of `Nullable<T>`. If `c_id` is null, then you will have to deal with that case otherwise you will get exception when casting.

As a side note, your assignment is slightly off, you can just do :

```
c_id = (txtBox_id.Text != string.Empty) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtBox_id.Text) : (int?)null;;
```

Comment: I tried this but i still get the error  "Cannot convert from 'int?' to 'int' "